# Pass a variable size value out of Filereader function for seperate manipulation

Tags: php, javascript, validation, asynchronous, filereader

I have a FileReader JS file called `filesize.js` containing the function `getsize()` that checks the size of an image file for client side validation before posting of a form.


`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/filesize.js"></script>`


***filesize.js:***

```
function getsize(){
var oFile = document.getElementById("file").files[0]; // input box with type file;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log(e.total); // file size 
};
reader.readAsDataURL(oFile );
fileSize = oFile.size;
}
```

The function runs when a file is selected for upload but before posting of the form by using `onchange` in the input tag.


`<input type='file' name='file' id='file' onchange='getsize();' />`


This gets the size of the currently selected file for upload since only one image can be uploaded at a time. The problem that I am running into is that `getsize()` is asynchronous and no matter what I have tried I am unable to pass the variable `fileSize` out to a separate synchronous validation function called `validate()` that needs to run separately before posting of the form using `onsubmit`.


`<form name='add' action='process.php' method='post'
enctype='multipart/form-data' onsubmit='return validate()'>`


`validate()` checks a few different factors before allowing the form to POST and upload the image. One of which is to verify that the file size of the currently selected image is under 512KB. Any help will be greatly appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a callback function. Basically, a callback function is a function that runs when a piece of code has finished running. In your case, you'd submit the form via the callback function. Have a look at [this article](http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/).